# Custom Delegate getting nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to create a custom delegate using TLPhotoControllerDelegate in swift. However the doSomething method is not being called through callback. It seems that delegate?. TLPhotoControllerDelegate() does not fire to the class B TLPhotoControllerDelegate method. Thanks in advance!

```
Class A: 
protocol TLPhotoControllerDelegate {
    func addimageCollectionView(image:UIImage)
}


class TLPhotoController: TLBaseViewController  {

    // Mark: Properties
    var delegate:TLPhotoControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }   

    @IBAction func capturePhoto(sender: TLButton) {
        delegate.addimageCollectionView(image)
    }
}

Class B:

class TLPatientAlbumCollectionViewController:TLPhotoControllerDelegate {

    var photoController:TLPhotoController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        photoController?.delegate = self

        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()  
    }   

    func addimageCollectionView(image: UIImage) {

    }
}
```

Comment: class TLPatientAlbumCollectionViewController:TLPhotoControllerDelegate {
            var photoController:TLPhotoController?
         override func viewDidLoad() {
                 photoController?.delegate = self
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
                loadData() 
         } 
             func addimageCollectionView(image: UIImage) {
          }
        }

Comment: Please add any additional code as an edit to your original question instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

From the code in your comment, it looks like you're not instantiating `TLPhotoController` anywhere?

Your code could look like this for example:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    photoController = TLPhotoController() // Or however you want to initialise
    photoController?.delegate = self
}
```

I'd also suggest putting a couple of breakpoints in to see the status of the variables when you think the code you be called, and see what's going on.

**Edit**
After clarifying the issue in chat, the problem was that the delegate wasn't being set. The solution proposed was to set it during `prepareForSegue:` on the pushing view controller.

Comment: I have initialise but still not getting called

Comment: Ok, would you mind updating the code in the question (with the code in the comment) with the latest. I ask because in that code you've posted so far it's not apparent where it gets initialised.

Comment: Sorry, but can you update it in the question instead of my answer, thanks.

Comment: photoController = TLPhotoController() But Still Its not calling

Comment: Again, please update the code in your question and not my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for updating this, shall we continue in chat? I think I have a few suggestions that will hopefully fix the problem for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104313/discussion-between-ollie-and-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not initializing your photoController property of TLPatientAlbumCollectionViewController class. You should initialize it in the viewDidLoad method.